# Когда надо применять буферизацию в php

Tags: php

Знаю что буферизация используется для того чтобы можно было отправлять заголовки в любом месте кода. А еще для чего используется?

P.S Изначально читал мануал, но там написано мало и вообще трудно понять для чего это все

Answer (score 2):

Буферизацию вывода стоит использовать всегда. Как минимум на то есть три причины:

1. Как вы уже сказали, можно отправлять заголовки на ходу. Как мы все с вами знаем, отправлять заголовки после  вывода контента в браузер пользователя нельзя, но буферизация решает эту проблему.
2. Когда мы буферизируем вывод, весь контент будет находиться в одной лишь переменной. А значит, мы сможем делать с этой переменной всё то же, что можно делать с обычными строками. Вот несколько кейсов, которые использовались лично мной:

   - замена `--` на `&mdash;` (длинное тире), `<<` на `&laquo;` (открывающая французская кавычка), `>>` на `&raquo;` (закрывающая французская кавычка), `(c)` на `&copy;` (символ копирайта)
   - сжатие всего HTML в одну единственную строку
   - можно закэшировать всю страницу разом без особых танцев с бубном
3. Некоторые утверждают, что из-за того, что контент отправляется одним большим куском в браузер, а не частями, то это повышает скорость загрузки страницы. В принципе, звучит правдоподобно, но сам я не проверял.

Comment: Если я понял буферизируется не сам код, а то что выводится на экран?

Comment: @MaximPro, верно. Всё, что должно вывестись на экран, накапливается в одной единственной переменной, а затем выводится лишь один раз в самом конце работы скрипта.

Comment: Я слышал что когда сервер использует буферизацию то нагрзука на сервер составляет около 40%. И вы сказали: "можно закэшировать всю страницу разом без особых танцев с бубном". Это если в начале кода написать `ob_start()`, а в конце скрипта `ob_end_flush`?

Comment: @MaximPro, буферизация как раз с помощью этих (и некоторых других) функций и работает. Про нагрузку, видимо, вы нашли ложные данные. Если и есть какая-то нагрузка, то только на шибко "толстых" страницах, да и не сказал бы, что это будет заметно.

Comment: И четвёртая причина - если не используется буфферизация, пользователь может наблюдать, как страница подгружается по частям: что порой страшно.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Половина Webа так и грузится =)

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Кстати при помощи буферизации можно добиться того самого эффекта =) Подгрузки кусками.

Comment: @MaximPro ага, и это будет ад-костылём. Человеческий способ - ajax

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр AJAX? Мне кажется что гораздо лучше использовать SSE или Sockets (кстати видел ваши статьи по сокетам на хабре,хорошие статьи опробую потом). Кстати есть что курнуть по сокетам, но чтобы углубленно? Интересует что-то вроде асинхронных сокетов. А то все как я понимаю пишут на синхронных плодя на каждый сокет свой(отдельный) процесс на сервере.

Comment: @MaximPro простите, думаю это однофамилец публиковал - на хабре меня вовсе нет :) SSE, Sockets - круто конечно, но это слишком свежо и необкатанно: потратится больше времени, проблем будет больше - чтобы сделать по сути банальную вещь. Тем не менее - сокеты идеальны для игр, тоже хотел бы их попинать, но пока времени нет..

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр понятно, просто сокеты это реал тайм информация в отличии от ajax, да и запросы посылать не нужно допустим каждую секунду, в отличии от сокетов которые держат соединение до момента отключения клиента

Comment: @MaximPro, сейчас нет возможности проверить, чтобы ответить точно, но надо начинать буферизацию функцией [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php) с флагом [`PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE`](http://php.net/manual/ru/outcontrol.constants.php#constant.php-output-handler-flushable), затем внутрь можно поместить какой-нибудь вывод, например, `echo 'foo';`, а затем вызовите функцию [`ob_get_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-get-flush.php) - она прервет процесс буферизации и вернет всё, что накопилось в течение этого самого процесса, напр. `$buffer = ob_get_flush();`.

Comment: @terron да я ступил, все правильно, просто функции с префиксом get тоже закрывают буфер, название укорочено! Я вот что еще хотел спросить: Есть так называемый пользовательский буфер вывода, а есть буфер вывода по умолчанию, тот что не требует вызова `ob_start()`. Так в чем различие между ними?

Comment: @terron Есть вопросы по работе с буфером вывода, не против подискутировать на эту тему?